# Liferay theme get portlet setup preferences

Tags: java, themes, liferay, portlet, velocity

I have a liferay portlet embedded in a theme. The theme is using the Velocity template language.

I would like to get the portlet setup preferences to the theme. 
Is there an idea to do it?

Liferay versio: 6.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Since you're embedding the portlet you'll have the portlet id.  Using that and the layout id you can get all of the portlet preferences like this:

```
#set ($portletPreferenceService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.PortletPreferencesLocalService"))
#set (portletPreferences = $portletPreferenceService.getPortletPreferences($theme_display.getLayout().getPlid(), "yourEmbeddedPortletId"))
```

Comment: But how I can specify wich portlet I would like to get preferences from?

Comment: I updated the answer to show how you can get all the preferences for a specific embedded portlet.